# Variable transformations in subsolutions of elliptic equations

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

I am reading Qing Han,& Fanghua Lin’s *elliptic partial differential equations*. The book had the following variable transformations. (proof of theorem 4.1)

> Suppose that $u\in H^1_0(B_1)$ is a subsolution in the following sense:
> $$\int_{B_1}a_{ij}D_iuD_j\varphi+cu\varphi\leq \int_{B_1}f\varphi\quad \text{for any }\varphi\in H^1_0(B_1)\text{ and }\varphi\geq 0\text{ in }B_1. $$
> Take any $R\leq 1$. Define
> $$\tilde{u}(y)=u(Ry)\quad\text{ for }y\in B_1.$$
> It is easy to see that $\tilde{u}$ satisfies the following equation:
> $$\int_{B_1}\tilde{a}_{ij}D_i\tilde{u}D_j\varphi+\tilde{c}\tilde{u}\varphi\leq \int_{B_1}\tilde{f}\varphi\quad \text{for any }\varphi\in H^1_0(B_1)\text{ and }\varphi\geq 0\text{ in }B_1. $$
> where
> $$\tilde{a}(y)=a(Ry),\quad \tilde{c}(y)=R^2c(Ry),\quad \tilde{f}(y)=R^2f(Ry),$$
> for any $y\in B_1.$

I thought it was a simple variable transformation, but there were a few things I did not understand. Why is the integral range still $B_1$ instead of $B_{R}$ ? Also, why do we need $R^2$ ? I would like someone to explain this to me.